# ERC777 granularity rounding error

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, javascript

I'm making a token with ERC777 standard.

I've got my `decimals` at 18, and I want whole tokens, so I set `granularity` to 10^18.

when I try to mint 20 tokens, I get granularity error.  So I made a function to see what the calculations are

```
function cal_Multiple(uint256 _amount) public pure returns(uint, uint) {
  uint cal =  (_amount.div(10^18).mul(10^18));
  return (_amount, cal);
}
```

I'm running tests via Truffle.
I want to make 20 tokens, with 18 decimals, and granularity of 10^18

```
let cal_mul = await Campaign_Deployer_inst.cal_Multiple(new web3.utils.BN('20000000000000000000'))
```

The result is

```
20000000000000000000 //value I sent in
19999999999999999992 //calculated value
```

This shouldn't be a JavaScript rounding error, the math is being some with the Solidity code.

Thanks for any help!!

UPDATE:
I changed it to 10**18, and the test returns the correct value thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation looks correct to me. `20000000000000000000` can't be evenly divided by `18` (the result is `1111111111111111111.11111...`), so doing an integer division results in truncation.

Did you maybe mean to divide and multiply by `10**18`?

**EDIT**

Your updated calculation divides and multiplies by `10^18` (`10` xor `18`), which is `24`. A similar problem ensues... `20000000000000000000` can't be evenly divided by `24`. I assume you really do want `10**18`.

Comment: oops sorry its supposed to be 10^18, updated, still getting rounding error

Comment: See my edit. 10^18=24